# Java function variables conflicts

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
    public static List<String> subsets(String s){
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringBuilder current = new StringBuilder();
        helper(s, 0, result, current);
        return result;
    }
    public static void helper(String s, int position, List<String> result, StringBuilder current){
        if(position >= s.length()){
            result.add(current.toString());
            return;
        }
        helper(s, position + 1, result, current.append(s.charAt(position)));
        current.delete(current.length() - 1, current.length());
        helper(s, position + 1, result, current);

    }
}
```

The above function tries to recursively find all the subsequence of a string. My question is with regard to the following codes:

```
        helper(s, position + 1, result, current.append(s.charAt(position)));
        current.delete(current.length() - 1, current.length());
        helper(s, position + 1, result, current);
```

when I called helper the first time and passed in current.append(s.charAt(position))) to it. Supposedly Java is passing the "value of the location" of current to the function and any changes done in helper to current will affect current(because even Java is passing by value, when you call the method of an object it will affect the initial object). So I assume the changes taken in place in the first helper will have an impact on the current which will cause a mess. But that does not seem to be the case since subsets returns the right result. Which part of my reasoning is wrong?

Comment: Recursive methods use stack. Maybe you'll figure it out if you understand how recursion works in the memory.

Comment: `append()` returns the same `StringBuilder` object, for the purpose of method chaining, so `helper(s, position + 1, result, current.append(s.charAt(position)));` is exactly the same as `current.append(s.charAt(position)); helper(s, position + 1, result, current);` --- It is true that Java is pass-by-value, but it is the reference value that is copied when calling the method. The referenced object, i.e. the `StringBuilder` object, is *not* copied, so all invocations of the `helper` method will see that *same* instance of `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @Andreas Great explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be missing with your reasoning, is that the `current.delete()` call is undoing the effect of the `current.append()`.

This is more evident if you extract the `append()` call:

```
current.append(s.charAt(position)); // append character
helper(s, position + 1, result, current);
current.delete(current.length() - 1, current.length()); // remove appended character
helper(s, position + 1, result, current);
```

So the code is calling itself twice, once *with* the character appended, and once *without* the character appended.

Note that both `append()` and `delete()` returns the `StringBuilder` instance itself, for the purpose of allowing method chaining, which means that the code could be condensed as follows:

```
helper(s, position + 1, result, current.append(s.charAt(position)));
helper(s, position + 1, result, current.delete(current.length() - 1, current.length()));
```

It just makes the code more difficult to follow, so you shouldn't do that. The code in the question did it for `append()`, but not for `delete()`, which is just even more confusing.

As you can see in the code in the first snippet above, all invocations of `helper` will have the *same* objects for `s`, `result`, and `current`. Only the `position` value changes, increasing by one the further down the recursion call stack you go.

Comment: I guess what confused me is the following: if the first helper is executed first, then it is going to change current further(not only appending something to its end, since as we go into the function there will be other changes implemented on current), now after we executed the first helper, current is completely changed. Isn't it going to affect the current passed to the second helper? But this reasoning is obviously not correct. I assume it is because the program is not naively executed in this order?

Comment: @z.z Using the first block above for reference, during the execution of `helper`, the value of `current` may be changed, but it will always be returned to the *original state* before `helper` returns. So after the first 3 lines have been executed, the value of `current` is *unchanged*. After the 4th lines has been executed, the value of `current` is still *unchanged*.

Comment: Okay, now I get it. It is a little bit mind-blowing to really try to figure this out, and sorry for dragging this so long. Would it be safer to just pass in a deep copy of current to each function, so one does not need to think about subtlety? But I assume it will be way less space efficient.

Comment: @z.z Safer? I don't know, the code is safe as it is. It would definitely be *slower* passing a deep copy.